# Simple Brainfuck Interpreter in C

Tags: c, interpreter, brainfuck

This is a simple interpreter for the esoteric [brainfuck programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), written in C. It is one of my personal projects and I would love to receive expert advice.

### Behavior

- All characters except the eight commands `><+-.,[]` are ignored and
  treated as comments.
- The array has 30,000 cells and each cell in the array contains a byte
  (most commonly 8 bits).
- Moving the pointer outside the bounds of the array will result in
  undefined behavior.

### Running

After successfully installing the interpreter, you can run it:

```
brain <file>
```

This is an example of running brain:

```
brain example.bf
```

You can visit the Git Repository at [gitlab.com/andy-sb/brain](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/brain) for building/compiling instructions and further information.

### Code

In `brain.c` I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void goto_open(char **codep)
{
    int search = 1;
    while (search > 0) {
        --*codep;
        switch (**codep) {
        case '[':
            --search;
            break;
        case ']':
            ++search;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

void goto_close(char **codep)
{
    int search = 1;
    while (search > 0) {
        ++*codep;
        switch (**codep) {
        case '[':
            ++search;
            break;
        case ']':
            --search;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

void exec_command(char **codep, char **memp)
{
    switch (**codep) {
    case '>':
        ++*memp;
        break;
    case '<':
        --*memp;
        break;
    case '+':
        ++**memp;
        break;
    case '-':
        --**memp;
        break;
    case '.':
        fputc(**memp, stdout);
        break;
    case ',':
        **memp = fgetc(stdin);
        break;
    case '[':
        if (!**memp)
            goto_close(codep);
        break;
    case ']':
        if (**memp)
            goto_open(codep);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void interpret(FILE *fp)
{
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char code[fsize];
    char *codep = code;
    fread(code, 1, fsize, fp);

    char mem[30000] = {0};
    char *memp = mem;

    while (*codep != '\0') {
        exec_command(&codep, &memp);
        ++codep;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed to open file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    interpret(fp);

    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is easy to read and to follow. There isn't a global in sight, the indentation is consistent, you use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, and the control flow is simple. Therefore I have no comments about superficial aspects of style.

---

However, there is a bug in `interpret`: You are reading uninitialized memory. The code assumes that `code` will end in a null character; this is not usually the case. Keep in mind that `ftell`, `fseek`, `fread` do not account for a terminating `\0`.

Most of the time, `fsize` will be the number of characters in the file. If the file happens to end in `\0`, all is well. But if it ends in some other fashion, then `code[fsize - 1]` (the last valid index of `code`) will not be `\0`. Hence `codep` will begin wandering into memory outside of `code` until it chances upon a 0.

In C, it is valid to have a pointer to one element past the end of an array. In other words, there is no issue having `codep > code + fsize`. The problem occurs when `codep` is dereferenced, since the contents of `*codep` is undefined.

You can fix this by reserving space for a null character and adding it yourself.

---

After fixing the problem, there are some other things to be careful about. You check the the return value of `fopen`, but you don't do the same for other input/output functions. For example, `fgetc`'s result is assigned to a cell blindly, even though `fgetc` does not return a `char`. It returns an `int`, which might be `EOF`; you should check for and handle this case, as long as the type of your cell is `char`. (See also the remarks on parameterization below.)

| Function name | Error return |
| --- | --- |
| `fputc` | `EOF` |
| `fgetc` | `EOF` |
| `fseek` | a nonzero value |
| `ftell` | `-1L` |
| `fread` | a value less than the third argument in the call |
| `fprintf` | a negative value |
| `fclose` | `EOF` |

My (somewhat controversial) stance on error checking is to do it for any function that can fail. Most people would probably not check `fputc` and `fprintf`, even if they check the others. I certainly don't object to this, but it isn't my personal choice.

In each failure case, you should `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`, probably after printing an indication of what happened. The `perror` function might be useful.

---

Why not perform bounds checking to avoid undefined behavior if the pointer moves outside the memory? You can print an error message and leave the pointer unchanged. A similar case to look out for is when a `[` or a `]` is missing. One way to handle bounds checking is to use offsets (probably of type `size_t`) instead of real pointers.

---

I would also suggest parameterizing the program a bit more. Your specification does say that the memory is 30 000 cells in size, but why not give the `30000` a symbolic name? But I think the most interesting aspect is the types you use.

For the most part, `char` works great as a cell type. However, there are two properties to note: (1) `char` might be wider than eight bits; (2) `char` might be signed or unsigned. The former is much less important than the latter. Because the signedness of `char` is uncertain, I would suggest using a fixed-width and fixed-signedness type.

Regardless of the underlying type, you should probably give a meaningful name to it with `typedef`—perhaps `cell_type`. I recommend doing this even if you stick with `char`.

Most brainfuck interpreters use signed, eight-bit cells. One choice of type is naturally `int8_t`, but such a type may not be provided by an implementation. You can test for its presence by checking whether `INT8_WIDTH` is defined. Alternatively, you could use `int_least8_t` or `int_fast8_t`, both of which are guaranteed to be provided by a conforming C implementation.

You should pay attention to overflow in memory cells, since overflow of signed numbers in C is undefined behavior. The simplest thing to do is to use unsigned types (`uint8_t`, `uint_least8_t`, `uint_fast8_t`), which wrap on overflow.

---

Finally, I should address your method of reading the input file. It is simple to read it all in at once, but `ftell` and `fseek` might fail, and you're wasting memory. An alternative is to store only the text associated with currently active loops. This is much more complicated to implement, however, especially if you want to allow loops to be arbitrarily sized.

Comment: Can I just set the condition `code < code + fsize` for the while-loop instead of reserving space for a null character and adding it myself?

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang Yes, that would work. Some people might find the null more natural, if `code` is supposed to be understood as a string. It's up to you.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, nice first answer.